# Error: Objects of type ts not supported by autoplot. Cannot knit RMarkdown (packages `fpp2` vs `fpp3`)

Tags: time-series, forecast, tsibble

I have a small problem with **Rob Hyndman's** packages `fpp2` and `fpp3`.

I have `ts` object

```
head(visitors)

[1] "ts"
      May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep   Oct
1985  75.7  75.4  83.1  82.9  77.3 105.7
```

Both packages `fpp2` and `fpp3` allow me to make a chart, using `autoplot` function.

```
autoplot(visitors)
```

[image]

But when I try to knit a RMarkdown report, I cannot do it, using `fpp3` package.

**Error: Objects of type ts not supported by autoplot.**

I read several responses, answered by Hyndman ([this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/repeated-troubles-using-autoplot-with-time-series-data-and-forecast-objects/35965) and [this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/can-not-use-autoplot-with-a-tsibble/41297)), but still not sure where is my error. I do not use `ggfortify`.

My `dput` is

```
structure(c(75.7, 75.4, 83.1, 82.9, 77.3, 105.7, 121.9, 150, 
98, 118, 129.5, 110.6, 91.7, 94.8, 109.5, 105.1, 95, 130.3, 156.7, 
190.1, 139.7, 147.8, 145.2, 132.7, 120.7, 116.5, 142, 140.4, 
128, 165.7, 183.1, 222.8, 161.3, 180.4, 185.2, 160.5, 157.1, 
163.8, 203.3, 196.9, 179.6, 207.3, 208, 245.8, 168.9, 191.1, 
180, 160.1, 136.6, 142.7, 175.4, 161.4, 149.9, 174.1, 192.7, 
247.4, 176.2, 192.8, 189.1, 181.1, 149.9, 157.3, 185.3, 178.2, 
162.7, 190.6, 198.6, 253.1, 177.4, 190.6, 189.2, 168, 161.4, 
172.2, 208.3, 199.3, 197.4, 216, 223.9, 266.8, 196.1, 238.2, 
217.8, 203.8, 175.2, 176.9, 219.3, 199.1, 190, 229.3, 255, 302.4, 
242.8, 245.5, 257.9, 226.3, 213.4, 204.6, 244.6, 239.9, 224, 
267.2, 285.9, 344, 250.5, 304.3, 307.4, 255.1, 214.9, 230.9, 
282.5, 265.4, 254, 301.6, 311, 384, 303.8, 319.1, 313.5, 294.2, 
244.8, 261.4, 329.7, 304.9, 268.6, 320.7, 342.9, 422.3, 317.2, 
392.7, 365.6, 333.2, 261.5, 306.9, 358.2, 329.2, 309.2, 350.4, 
375.6, 465.2, 342.9, 408, 390.9, 325.9, 289.1, 308.2, 397.4, 
330.4, 330.9, 366.5, 379.5, 448.3, 346.2, 353.6, 338.6, 341.1, 
283.4, 304.2, 372.3, 323.7, 323.9, 354.8, 367.9, 457.6, 351, 
398.6, 389, 334.1, 298.1, 317.1, 388.5, 355.6, 353.1, 397, 416.7, 
460.8, 360.8, 434.6, 411.9, 405.6, 319.3, 347.9, 429, 372.9, 
403, 426.5, 459.9, 559.9, 416.6, 429.2, 428.7, 405.4, 330.2, 
370, 446.9, 384.6, 366.3, 378.5, 376.2, 523.2, 379.3, 437.2, 
446.5, 360.3, 329.9, 339.4, 418.2, 371.9, 358.6, 428.9, 437, 
534, 396.6, 427.5, 392.5, 321.5, 260.9, 308.3, 415.5, 362.2, 
385.6, 435.3, 473.3, 566.6, 420.2, 454.8, 432.3, 402.8, 341.3, 
367.3, 472, 405.8, 395.6, 449.9, 479.9, 593.1, 462.4, 501.6, 
504.7, 409.5), .Tsp = c(1985.33333333333, 2005.25, 12), class = "ts")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `fpp2` package depends on the `forecast` package which contains an `autoplot()` function that handles `ts` objects.

The `fpp3` package depends on the `feasts` package which contains an `autoplot()` function that handles `tsibble` objects.

Since you have a `ts` object, you need the `fpp2` or `forecast` package. Make sure you load it in the Rmd file (using `library(forecast)`) before you call `autoplot()`.